# How to route all traffic of wlan0 to eth0 in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, routing, bridge

I'm trying to route/bridge/forward (no matter what kind of trickery) all the traffic from `wlan0` to `eth0`. My setup should look like this:

|*wireless network*| > |**wlan0**| > |**eth0**| > |*router*| > |*another wireless network*|

So basically `eth0` should output something a router can understand. I did my research and so far:

- *bridge-utils* does not work
- Ubuntu's Network Manager does not work (IPv4 "Shared with other computers" mode)

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IP forwarding needs to be enabled for this to work. By default it's set to 0, you can turn it on by setting it to 1 with this command.

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

This might be enough by itself, if it isn't, then try configuring the default gateway so that traffic automatically goes out of eth0.